# Including external resources through a view that extends a layout

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to learn Laravel by using it for one of my sites however I'm having trouble working something out.

I have a `layout.blade.php` file which holds all my global markup. Stuff like the header, footer etc. I'm also including some external stuff like stylesheets and scripts in `<head>` like this:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js'); }}
```

However, there's some external stuff that I only want to load on certain pages. I'm including individual views from the header like this:

```
<div id="content">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

and in the views I'm extending the layout like so:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <h1>some content</h1>
@stop
```

How can I use a `HTML::script` type function to include stuff in my `<head>` from a view that extends `layout.blade.php`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `layout.blade.php`, wrap your `HTML::script` calls in a `@section()` and `@show` tags, and simply extend them afterwards, in your child view, just like you did with section, but also using `@parent` to include the parent's content. Example:

**layout.blade.php**

```
@section('javascript')
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
@show
```

**childview.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')

// ...

@section('javascript')
    @parent

    {{ HTML::script('js/customScript.js') }}
@stop
```